# How can someone get FAA commercial flight training as part of an aviation degree?

Tags: flight-training, usa

If someone can't afford to pay for flight training directly, is it possible to get commercial flight training with financial aid as part of a college degree?

---

For the UK answer, see: [Do any UK universities include PPL/Commercial flight training as part of an aviation degree?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11366/65)

Comment: ERAU's cost calculator estimates $120,000 for tuition, books, room and board over 4 years and around 90,000 for flight training. That is 210,000 in student loans and the monthly payment wont be pretty, especially as the only aviation job open to you when you walk out the door is likely instructing until you have the experience for 135 or 121 operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US, there are 2 ways to become a certificated civilian pilot: [Part 61](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=898af63a181cfab86749b6fb139dcef0&node=pt14.2.61&rgn=div5) and [Part 141](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr141_main_02.tpl).

Part 61 is done in informal classes and flights at a local flight school.

Part 141 is a professional pilot training program, with uniforms, classrooms, a full-time staff, and a uniform fleet of aircraft.

There are numerous US universities that offer bachelors' degrees using a part 141 program. You can find [a list of such programs here](http://www.globalair.com/directories/Colleges-Universities-38.html).

Furthermore, many of these schools, such as [Embry-Riddle](http://daytonabeach.erau.edu/admissions/estimated-costs/index.html), take the [FAFSA](https://fafsa.ed.gov/), which is the  process for obtaining financial aid as for any other program.

After graduating from one of these programs, you will have obtained all the training necessary to work as a flight instructor, or as a commercial pilot under [Part 119](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=898af63a181cfab86749b6fb139dcef0&node=pt14.3.119&rgn=div5)

- Private Pilot Single Engine
- Instrument Pilot Single and Multi-Engine
- Commercial Pilot Single and Multi-Engine
- Flight Instructor Single Engine
- Flight Instructor Instrument
- Multi-Engine Flight Instructor

You will have also earned either an Associates or Bachelors degree, usually in something like Aviation Engineering or Aviation Operations.

You will not, however, have flown enough hours to get a job flying air taxi or cargo under [Part 135](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=898af63a181cfab86749b6fb139dcef0&node=pt14.3.135&rgn=div5), which requires 500 hours to be the pilot-in-command.

Comment: A part 61 program can be quite professional, you dont need to be 141 to have the things you use to describe it. Part 141 is a structured, approved curriculum that allows certain things 61 does not and some subtle differences in requirements.

Comment: No you don't, but that's the way it is. And this is a question about university programs, which are all 141

Comment: Its also worth mentioning a university degree + flight training program will likely cost more than either a degree or flight training alone costs combined. If you cannot pay for training can you afford the massive student loan debt you'll incur in such a program?

Comment: Somebody must be going into these programs. I don't think it's the 1%ers

Comment: no, not only 1%ers.  It was also the first officers I flew with that told me of their struggles paying off their loans on first and second year FO pay and wishing they'd gone a different route.

Comment: I did a Part 61 program at Embry-Riddle for my PPL.  It was almost identical to their 141 program, but I'm not pursuing a career in commercial aviation (engineering major) so I wanted the freedom available with Part 61.

Comment: [ATP](https://atpflightschool.com/airline-career-pilot-program/index.html) offers to become an airline pilot for ~$75,000 (including housing). They are Part 141.

Comment: In general, the colleges which offer flight training do so at premium costs.  Frequently connected students will conduct their flight training with other providers, or during the summer, to reduce costs. There are quite a few community colleges also offering aviation programs, and their cost points are frequently more favorable than places like Embry-Riddle and Daniel Webster.  I have provided CFI initial training and signoffs to quite a few Daniel Webster students.